# Check how many DateTimes from a table fits between a range of DateTimes

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

```
DECLARE @dateFrom   DATETIME;
DECLARE @dateTo     DATETIME;

declare @tempholidays table (holidays datetime);

insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-01-01'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-02-19'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-04-06'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-04-09'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-05-01'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-05-28'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-08-15'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-12-25'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-12-26'));
```

I have a temp table with some Datetimes.
Ι would like to know how many of these entries exist in a specific range of datetimes (dateFrom,dateTo). For example if i give the range (datefrom='2018-05-27' and dateto='2018-05-29') the result should be 1.

Comment: Would the result be 3 if you specified from=05-01 & to=08-15 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @dateFrom   DATETIME;
DECLARE @dateTo     DATETIME;

declare @tempholidays table (holidays datetime);

insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-01-01'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-02-19'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-04-06'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-04-09'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-05-01'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-05-28'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-08-15'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-12-25'));
insert into @tempholidays values(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-12-26'));

set @dateFrom = 'May 27, 2018'
set @dateTo = 'May 29, 2018'

select
    count(*) countx
from
    @tempholidays h
where
    h.holidays between @dateFrom and @dateTo
```

Comment: try: set @dateFrom = '2018-05-27', this format is global using yours will change depending on the server language

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select count(*)
from @tempholidays th
where th.date >= @datefrom and th.date <= @dateto;
```